# Looking for a cheap rugged phone

Tags: android, smartphones

I'm a very clumsy person and I "regularly" drop my phone, sometimes onto hard ground. My most recent phone was the Moto G4 and it was amazing: it was cheap, indestructable (almost!) and had a great screen (1080p which I've not seen much of at that price range).

I'm looking for a similar phone to that but I of course want a slightly newer one as the moto G4 is still stuck on android 7 and I like to keep resonably up-to-date. As for the actual specs, I don't need much: the moto G4 had a perfectly adiquate CPU, GPU, RAM, battery life, storage and the rest.

The price range I'm looking for is <£200/$~220.

**I must stress that the point I'm looking for here is robustness, specs come after.** (but are still fairly important)

Reletively stock android is also a plus (i.e. from what I've heard, not samsung, although I may be wrong). Ease of rooting is also a plus.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the local prices for the Samsung Xcover 4 / 4s? https://www.notebookcheck.net/Rugged-Smartphone-Samsung-Galaxy-XCover-4s-in-Review-A-Rarity-for-Outdoor-Smartphone-Fans.428745.0.html  They both accept Android 9 Pie and are well documented.

Comment: Checkout Honor 9X and Asus 6Z both are Robust Phone but asus have higher specs in this budget .

Comment: maybe a [Doogee S40](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32975433765.html) ? warning tho, i had a Doogee S80 (their flagship rugged phone at the time) and the camera was horrible. everything else was fine, and the 10,080mAh battery was magical (could go 10 days between charging), but the camera was shit.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a very rugged case, such as an [Otterbox](https://www.otterbox.com/), [Urban Armor Gear](https://www.urbanarmorgear.com/),  or [Ballistic Hardcore](http://information.goballisticcase.com/hardcore-series-info.html), would be a less spendy solution as well as providing more protection than the much more expensive phones deliberately designed for ruggedness. Then, you would have your choice of phones which meet all your other wishes.

Comment: I fully agree with this. To add to the benefits. A case and screen protector(don't forget to grab a decent one of those) can be removed and replaced if damaged or broken. With a rugged phone, you're stuck replacing the phone. Being able to revert it to a normal phone also helps in reselling or passing on the phone to someone else. 

Lastly, rugged phones are usually still flat at the front, so there are no case bumps that can protect the screen. Making them worse at protecting your screen than even the most basic cases. edit: sorry for the late comment, did not notice the community bump

Answer (score 0):

I had the Kyocera Duraforce Pro for a while and loved it.  The sapphire shield worked really well as it never cracked or even got a scratch on the screen.  I dropped that think all the time and it was still in very good condition after I bought it.  The phone is outdated but they did make the Duraforce Pro 2, which would probably be a great choice.  You can get one on eBay for around $200 USD.

Comment: lol didn't notice the community bump either.  Oh well.